# Spot redundant equations within nonlinear system of equations.

Tags: matrix-rank, nonlinear-system, least-squares

Is there a general procedure to detect if in a system of m-nonlinear equations (also non polynomial) of n-unknowns some of the equations are redundant?
Can the rank of the Jacobian matrix tell me something?
The systems I handle is usually underdetermined, so m is less or equal to n.

**How I numerically solve the system:**
I use the iterative Gauss-Newton method. Since there are more unknowns than equations, I solve the linear equation involving the Jacobian matrix in the least squares sense. I was thinking that if the rank of the Jacbian matrix is not maximum at the solution point, then there must be some redundant equations. Actually the pair of equations
eq 1: $y_1 - y_2 = 10$ eq 2: $(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2=100$ with unknowns $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$
is non-redundant, but the rank of the Jacobian matrix is 1 in the subset where $x_1=x_2$. Maybe evaluating the Jacobian Rank only at one point is not enough?

I found a similar discussion here https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-to-detect-redundant-equation-from-a-system-of-nonlinear-equation.418848/

Comment: For polynomial equations algorithms that compute [Groebner basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Membership_and_inclusion_of_ideals), like [Buchberger's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm) can do this.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the equations may not be polynomial. Maybe I can add it to the description

Comment: What are they? What do you know about them?

Comment: They may be equations that derive from a distance (therefore involving a square root) or equations related to angles and therefore involving trigonometric functions

Comment: Square roots can be squared, and trigonometric function can be turned into rational functions, with [the right change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution). Clearing denominators rational functions turn into polynomials. So, after some massaging your equations become polynomial equations and you are still good with the algorithms above.

Comment: There can be also different type of equations. I can't reformulate those equations for all cases, so I need insights also for non polynomial one.

Comment: If you don't know your problem, you cannot know your solution. It doesn't take much complexity of the type of equations to not even be able to tell if a single equation is the equation $0=0$ or not. See [Richardson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for thanking time to try to answer my question . I also added a description on how I solve the equation system. Maybe this can help to find an insight.

Comment: I found a similar discussion here https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-to-detect-redundant-equation-from-a-system-of-nonlinear-equation.418848/